# Is it possible to reply to a list collection using SMTP ReplyToList

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, smtp

I am using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` to create an SMTP email. And can replytolist be used to reply ALL to the list?

`mess.ReplyToList.Add(new Mail.MailAddress(address1, name1));`
`mess.ReplyToList.Add(new Mail.MailAddress(address2, name2));`

I know it will only reply to `address1`, but is there a way to reply to all the list?